# How can I take the first values from a list of dictionaries and create another list with it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regression, linear-regression

I am very new to python and machine learning and i searched for this specific question but could not find something useful.
I have a list:

```py
data=[{'a':1,
        'b':2},
        {'a':3,
         'b':4}]
```

I want a separate list for a and b with their values. For example:

```py
a=[1,3] 
b=[2,4]
```

I tried to do:

```py
a=[lst['a'] for lst in data] 
b=[lst['b'] for lst in data]
```

but the elements in a and b become a string?For example, i can not multiply a[0] and b[1].
I'd be so glad to hear if anyone has a solution for this or any advice to do something better. Sorry if I could not explain more clearly, like I said I am very new to all of this and I do not know the terminology etc. whatsoever. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You example is not so clear, please focus on a minimal but **complete** example in which you would provide both the input and the exact matching expected output

Comment: Do you mean `xData=[{'X1':0, 'X3':3, 'X4':3, 'X5':3, 'X6':3}, {'X1:5, 'X2':8 etc.}]` instead of `xData=[{'X1':0, 'X3':3, 'X4':3, 'X5':3, 'X6':3}, 'X1:5, 'X2':8 etc.}]` if I'm right you are missing a `{` before `X1:5`

Comment: Can you give us a code that you are currently using so we can recreate the same problem?

Comment: How many elements should be in new lists?

Comment: I edited my question so i can explain the main problem in a simpler way @BokiX

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have a list of dicts, with identical keys, then in that case you could use the the library called Pandas and its DataFrames, which essentially is a Matrix. If you're working with machine learning you'll most likely use this library quite a lot anyways. But then you can select a specific column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(list)

    x1  x2  x3
0   1   2   3
1   1   2   3
2   1   2   3
```

If you now want the select all values for x1, simply do

```
x1_values = df["x1"] # returns [1, 1, 1]
```

To get the product of each row, you can do this:

```
df.prod(axis=1) # returns [6, 6, 6]
```

The you get product for the whole row, however many rows you might should have

Comment: This is not a forum, do not post requests for clarifications as answers. Only actual answers should be posted as answers.

Comment: Sorry about that, I've updated my answer

Comment: Yes,that was my question and i edited it to maybe make it simpler.So with this solution if i were to calculate x1*x2*x3 for each line how would i do that?

Comment: I've updated the answer which hopefully should be what you're looking for

Comment: What could i do in the case that i have to do x1+x2-x3 for each line?

Comment: That would be `df.sum(axis=1)`

And please mark the question as answered if my answer, answered your question :)